# Back Button Arrow from Fragment to previous home fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 5 fragments and every fragment has three dots in top right corner which allows user to go to another child fragment. When user enter that fragment I want to allow them to go back to fragment they were before using back button arrow in right corner. I know if I had activities instead of fragments I could just do it in Android Manifest. I don't know if it is possible to call onClick() method on back arrow button because I created it through code so it does not have an id to select it.

[Back Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA6y6.png)

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected`  to define the action you need when the home/back button is clicked

Comment: @Zain ok, and I suppose that I need switch(item.getItemId()) and in case select that back button, but I don't know how to make case for that because I created back arrow button in code as I've shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable access to the home/up button from fragment you need to override and check item ID of `android.R.id.home`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:

            // Do whatever you want here on home/up button click

            // Replacing a fragment
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("xyz");
            fragmentTransaction.hide(MyCurrentFragment.this);
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what I need to do with R.id.android.R.id.home because "android" part is giving me syntax error

Comment: @SvatsQ12 sorry it's typo .. you can check it now `android.R.id.home`

Comment: @SvatsQ12 yes you still need to add the logic you want when you hit the home button .. just replace the commented out line above

Comment: I replaced it with FragmentHelper.getInstance().switchFragments(new Fragment1(), this);
that is my method for switching fragments

Comment: @SvatsQ12 does this method work for you .. You didn't provide the `FragmehtHelper`

Comment: @SvatsQ12 please check the answer updated with how to replace the fragment when the home button is hit

Comment: Yeah it works, I also made toast message before that method and when I click button back arrow toast message does not even pop up

Comment: @SvatsQ12 did you add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` to `onCreateView` method ?

Comment: Thats what I forgot, it works now, thank you very much sir